# determine if element is last visibile element

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I have a bunch of drop downs and I want to know the most efficient way to determine if the drop down just changed is the last visible drop down in the list. Right now this code just checks if the one just changed is the last one not the last visible one.

```
<div id="dropdownArea">
   <div>
      <select id="select1"></select>
   </div>
   <div>
      <select id="select2"></select>
   </div>
   <div style="display: none;">
      <select id="select3"></select>
   </div>
   <div style="display: none;">
      <select id="select4"></select>
   </div>
</div>
```

target = the select that just changed;

```
if($(target).parent().index() === $("#dropdownArea").children().length - 1){
   //do stuff
}
```

New code:

```
var dddivs = $("#dropdownArea").children().filter(":visible");
if($(dddivs).index(target) === $("#dropdownArea").children().length - 1){
   //do stuff
}
```

Will that work? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to test for equality of jQuery objects. Other than that I would append [.last](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to get the last visible select and pass a selector to the [.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method to remove the need for a filter:

```
var lastVisibleSelect = $("#dropdownArea").children(":visible").last();
if($(this).parent().is(lastVisibleSelect)){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Nice, never knew you could pass an element to `is`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the use of .is(). I put the "display: none;" on the wrong element. But I have fixed it now.

Comment: You can just change `.children(':visible')` to `.find('select:visible')`.

Comment: @BillCriswell I think `.children` is more appropriate in this case. `.find('select:visible')` would find all child elements (including option and optgroup) rather than direct children, then work backwards to find their tagname. Granted in the provided sample case they are equivalent.

Comment: RGraham: Understood. The question has adjusted itself a few times haha. Cypher: You can do `$(this).parent().is(lastVisibleSelect)` with RGraham's code above instead of `$(this).is(lastVisibleSelect)` and just ignore my first comment.

Comment: Yes sorry the only change was putting the "display:none" on the div not the select. Thanks for the idea it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var $selects = $('select');

$selects.on('change', function () {
  var $select = $(this);
  var startIndex = $selects.index($select);
  var visibleNextSiblingsLength = $selects.slice(startIndex + 1).filter(':visible').length;
  if (visibleNextSiblingsLength === 0) {
    console.log('You just changed the last visible select');
  }
});
```

Though RGraham's is probably better.